# How to make zoom in the form contain in c#?

Tags: c#

i have project in c# and i want to do zoom on the image displayed in the form without using panel or picture box. Please, how its possible to make scrolling in the form using scroll-bar? thanks for all.

Comment: Did you try something? Any piece of code? Any idea?

Comment: Where are the restrictions coming from?